# Is this an exception safe implementation of swap(multithread)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

From the examples of the book C++ Concurrency in Action

Example (3.2.4)

```
friend void swap(X& lhs, X& rhs)
{
    if (&lhs == &rhs)
        return;
    std::lock(lhs.m, rhs.m); #1
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m, std::adopt_lock); #2
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m, std::adopt_lock); #3
    swap(lhs.some_detail, rhs.some_detail);            ￼￼￼￼￼￼
}
```

What if exception thrown on another thread when we are on #2 and #3?

The other example (3.2.6) looks better (although slower and bigger since `unique_guard` is more expensive)

```
friend void swap(X& lhs, X& rhs)
{
    if (&lhs == &rhs)
        return;        
    std::unique_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m, std::defer_lock); #1
    std::unique_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m, std::defer_lock); #2
    std::lock(lhs.m, rhs.m); #3
    swap(lhs.some_detail, rhs.some_detail);            ￼￼￼￼￼￼
}
```

Is the example of 3.2.4 not exception safe? Or I miss something? Thanks.

Naive example

```
class some_big_object;
void swap(some_big_object& lhs,some_big_object& rhs);
class X
{
private:
    some_big_object some_detail;
    std::mutex m;
public:
    X(some_big_object const& sd):some_detail(sd){}
    friend void swap(X& lhs, X& rhs)
    {
        if(&lhs==&rhs)
            return;
        std::lock(lhs.m,rhs.m); #A1
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m,std::adopt_lock); #A2
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m,std::adopt_lock); #A3
        swap(lhs.some_detail,rhs.some_detail);

        ￼￼￼￼￼￼} 
};

void threadA()
{
  X A, B;
  //do something
  swap(A, B);
}

void threadB()
{
   //do something
   throw std::runtime_error("error");
}

void testSwap()
{
  std::thread tA(threadA);
  std::thread tB(threadB);

  tA.join();
  tB.join();
}
```

My problem is, what if threadB throw exception when threadA processing #A2?
The mutex already lock, but the lock_guard may not ready for the mutexs yet.

Comment: you know, the book has a fansite (forum) on manning.com. A considerable number of requests for clarification have been answered by the author, there

Comment: "What if exception thrown on another thread when we are on #2 and #3?" that's irrelevant, since the exception should not propagate to the current thread (except via e.g. a `future/promise` - which implies synchronization.

Comment: @sehe Could I interpret your word as "The exception occur in thread A would not force thread B quit the process"? Try to link to the author online forum with no luck(http://www.manning-sandbox.com/category.jspa?categoryID=3).

Comment: On the contrary: if an exception in thread A were to affect the other thread, the only effect could have been process termination. If the other thread handled the situation, then there is no (immediate) effect on other threads whatsoever, except the ones explicitly coded for using synchronization. Also: [where did you get that link from?!?!](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/forum.jspa?forumID=437)

Comment: Please explain what exception safety problem you're referring to. So what if an exception is thrown in another thread?

Comment: @sehe Thanks for your link, I get the link from the homepage of the manning.com(http://www.manning.com/).

Comment: @sere I should change my question to--"if the exception throw from threadB is handle properly, if would not cause the other threads exit(wouldn't affect other threads)".

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely I update the post with a small example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They look exception safe to me.

In the first example the equality comparison could throw, or the call to `std::lock` at #1 can throw, but if it does the function exits without changing anything.  The object initializations at #2 and #3 cannot throw, the standard says so.  The call to `swap` might throw, but if it does the mutexes are unlocked by the `unique_lock` destructors.

In the second example, the equality comparison can throw, the initializations at #1 and #2 are `noexcept`, the `std::lock` call could throw, but if it does the function exits with no effects. The call to swap could throw, but if it does the mutexes are unlocked by the `unique_lock` destructors.

You seem to be implying that exceptions in a separate threads interact with the thread doing the swapping, but that's not true. Exceptions in one thread do not affect execution of other threads.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I was implying that exceptions in a separate threads would interact(propagate) to other threads.Now they look exception safe for me.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to have to get this book and see what it actually says,
because it *is* highly regarded.  Never the less:

- Implementing a thread safe swap is non-trivial, regardless of the
  situation.  Generally, the thread safety issues must be handled at a
  higher level.
- Neither of the solutions you show work; they both result in deadlocks.
- The only solution which works is to have a single mutex for *all*
  instances of `X`, and use a `unique_guard` on that, at the top of the
  `swap` function.

(In the end, exceptions don't enter into it here.  But you are right to think about them, because they can make an otherwise safe solution unsafe.)

Comment: Why deadlock?I though std::lock is designed for locking two mutex simutaneously?

Comment: @StereoMatching "simultaneously" would be surprising, considering that the implementatio needs to be portable. More likely "in deterministic order"

Comment: "Also, it’s worth noting that locking either lhs.m or rhs.m inside the call
to std::lock can throw an exception; in this case, the exception is propagated out
of std::lock. If std::lock has successfully acquired a lock on one mutex and an
Listing 3.6 Using std::lock() and std::lock_guard in a swap operation
b
c
d
Licensed to Seth Heeren <manning@sehe.nl>
Protecting shared data with mutexes 49
exception is thrown when it tries to acquire a lock on the other mutex, this first lock is
released automatically: std::lock provides all-or-nothing semantics with regard to
locking the supplied mutexes."

Comment: ^ that's taken from p48/49 in section 3.2.4

Comment: I'm not that familiar with C++11, and I don't have a copy of it on this machine to verify, but "in a deterministic order" could mean `lhs`, then `rhs`, no?  (Regardless: my first point is the essential one: this should be handled at a higher level.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah, my wording wasn't the standardese, of course. Anyways, std::lock was designed to avoid deadlocks. I imagine it using some kind of implementation-dependent stable ordering of the Lockable objects.

Comment: ***§30.4.3 ad 5:*** _Effects:_ All arguments are locked via a sequence of calls to `lock()`, `try_lock()`, or `unlock()` on each
argument. The sequence of calls shall not result in deadlock, but is otherwise unspecified. [ _Note:_ A
deadlock avoidance algorithm such as try-and-back-off must be used, but the specific algorithm is not
specified to avoid over-constraining implementations. _—end note_ ]

Comment: James, `std::lock` exists specifically to lock multiple mutexes without a deadlock, so you need to justify your assertion that both solutions result in deadlock.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Well, I do and I don't.  I don't have access here to the C++11 standard, but apparently, they don't result in a deadlock.  But the fact remains that if you need such sort of tricks, you have a design flaw at a higher level.  My first point is still valid: this is a problem which should be resolved at a higher level.  (Even without C++, I've seen code which used various hacks to avoid the deadlock.  But it's an example of poor design.)

Comment: You can get the standard easily enough, or a draft for free, see http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Comment: @JonathanWakely I've got it on other machines.